# How should I align a text ignoring a floating <div> in the same level?

Tags: html, css

First check this one out. I put an image button floating no the right end; and the title is slightly moved to the left.

[image]

But the title is supposed to be in the center like below:

[image]

I think the space for the title is narrowed a bit because the image button takes a bit of space.

This is the html source.

```
<div class="title">TourismKorea
    <div class="menubtn">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/menuicon.png" style="height: 100%;"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I gave them styles like this:

```
.title{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f8f8f8;

    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;}

.menubtn{
    float: right;
    margin: 0.2rem 0.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    border: 0;
    /*display: none;*/
}
```

So the title pane must ignore the space given to the menu button. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can:

- set in `absolute` the floating element

```css
.title{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, gray 50%);
    position:relative;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;}

.menubtn{
    float: right;
    margin: 0.2rem 0.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    width:1.2rem;
    border: 0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">TourismKorea
    <div class="menubtn">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/menuicon.png" alt="X" style="height: 100%;"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

- add an equal negative `margin` to reduce its `width` virtually down to zero

```css
.title{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, gray 50%);
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;}

.menubtn{
    float: right;
    margin: 0.2rem 0.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    width:1.2rem;
    margin-left:-1.2rem;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">TourismKorea
    <div class="menubtn">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/menuicon.png" alt="X" style="height: 100%;"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

- add a `:before` floating pseudo of same `width`.

```css
.title{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, gray 50%);
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;}
.title:before {
content:'';
float:left;
width:1.2rem;
height:1.2rem;
}
.menubtn{
    float: right;
    margin: 0.2rem 0.2rem;
    height: 1.2rem;
    width:1.2rem;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">TourismKorea
    <div class="menubtn">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/menuicon.png" alt="X" style="height: 100%;"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Third example can be turned into flex to easy set vertical-alignement of text and burgermenu

Comment: the second one is the easiest but think i've gotta practice the first one.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The menu button (or img) will move the centered text, as it is still in the layout flow. To fix this, you may try making the `.title` relatively-positioned, and then absolutely-position the `.menubtn` inside it, and give it a `right: 0`.

Here is an example:

```css
.title{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  text-align: center;
}

.menubtn{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0.2rem 0.2rem;
  height: 1.2rem;
  border: 0;
  /*display: none;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="title">TourismKorea
    <div class="menubtn">
        <a href="#">=</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try it yourself. Hope that answered it well.